# Sources of non-determinism of Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, non-deterministic

I am trying to figure out all sources of non-determinism in Spark. I understand that non-determinism can come from user provided functions e.g in a map(f) with f involving random. I am instead looking for the operations that can lead to non-determinism either in terms of transformations/actions of at a lower level e.g shuffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- operations which require shuffling (or network traffic in general) may output values in non-deterministic order. It includes obvious cases like `groupBy*` or `join`. A less obvious example is an order of ties after sorting
- operations which depend on the changing data sources or a mutable global state
- side effects executed inside transformations, including `accumulator` updates

Comment: Can you give an example of a side effect inside a transformation?

Comment: Communication with external system, writing to file, updating "global" executor state.

Comment: don't forget pretty much any operation that gets a timestamp or an environment variable, since they vary from node to node